# Code in External jquery file does not get fired without an alert

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have an external js file that needs to get fired when a certain element is clicked. This code is inside the ready function. When I have an alert statement inside the ready function everything works fine. but when I remove the alert, 
the ready function is not getting called. What could possibly be the reason for this strange behavior?

```
alert()
    $(".monthChanger span").click(function (event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            $(".monthChanger span ul").show();
        });
```

without this alert call the above code does not get fired. This code is inside the ready() function

Comment: I would imagine the `alert()` to allow something to get loaded during, which else doesn't have the time to load without `alert()`.

Comment: you can use jsFiddle.net to post a mockup of your code! its really a good way to share your problem with the community, and also a good way for us to provide solutions back to you!

Comment: If you can post some code..then only anyone can look into this issue...

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the external file is loaded AND executed before the ".monthChanger span" is loaded.
Triggers in jQuery only work for elements that already exist at the time the trigger is loaded (at least those triggers you're using, There are other jQuery functions ( .live ) that don't need to be loaded after the code of the selector is ready, in order to work).

To solve this you could rely on the ".live" jQuery function, try a $(document).ready() for the external file (I'm not sure that one would work, though, or just make sure the javascript file is loaded later than the elements it relies on (simply by placing the  below the elements it needs.